# Is there a formula for finding the lowest common factor

Tags: algorithms

Us there an formula/algorithm for finding the lowest/least common factor/denominator (other than one) of two numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean either "least common multiple" or "greatest common divisor"?  Otherwise, it would be 1 every time...

Answer (score 2):

To find least common divisor greater than $1$ do following:

Find greatest common divisor using Euclidean Algorithm.
$$g=GCD(a,b)$$
If $g$ is $1$, then there is no factor greater than $1$.
Otherwise, find smallest prime factor of $g$.
It can be done by finding remainder of $g$ divided by every prime smaller or equal to $\sqrt{g}$ until remainder is $0$.
That prime will be least common divisor greater than $1$.
If no such prime found, then least common divisor will equal to $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Given two numbers $a, b$:

$lcm(a,b) = \frac{ab}{gcd(a,b)}$

To calculate $gcd(a,b)$, you'll need to go through the Euclidean Algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: I am asking for the lowest common factor not the least common multiple.

Comment: You may mean the *greatest* common factor. The least (positive) common factor is $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I mean least common factor other than one.

Comment: There may not be such a thing, indeed there often isn't: example, $48$ and $65$. Also, if $m$ is odd and we look at the two numbers $m$ and $2m$, then finding the least common factor $\gt 1$ is equivalent to factoring $m$, a problem that appears to be computationally difficult for large $m$.